# CPython Python.h on macOS

Tags: macos, python, c++

I'm trying to compile C++ code for a Python3 extension on macOS, and I'm only able to compile if I `#include "$HOME/anaconda3/include/python3.6m/Python.h`. Is there a way to `#include <Python/Python.h>` and have the "include" refer to the anaconda Python.h instead of the system Python.h?

Answer (score 1):

Having your `Python.h` inside a directory named `python3.6m` makes it a bit awkward, but here are two possible ways to resolve the issue:

1. Rename the directory from python3.6m to Python, and then add the argument `-I$HOME/anaconda3/include` to your compile line, to tell the compiler to resolve include-paths starting at that folder.
2. Alternatively, you could add a symlink so that the python3.6m directory can be accessed via two different names, e.g.:

   cd ~/anaconda3/include ; ln -s python3.6m Python

... and then add the argument `-I$HOME/anaconda3/include` to your compiler arguments (same as in step 1)